# Convert es6 string in dot into an formData key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given a JS string

```
let string = 'language.0.name'
```

how can I convert the string to formData key notation so I can go

```
'language[0][name]'
```

I try this but I want short code with regular expression

```
let temp = '';
_.forEach(key.split(/[.]/), (i, k) => {
   temp += k === 0 ? i : `[${i}]`;
});
```

Comment: For form encoded data wouldn't you want `'language[0][name]'`? What is your actual use case? Also what have you tried?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, you are right, I updated my questions. I want to send ajax request with post method to my server side . my input have multiple data..
`
languages [
    {level : 5, name : 'english'},
    {level : 5, name : 'english'}
]
`

Comment: Why not send as JSON since you seem to have structured data already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can do this with a simple `split()` and `reduce()`

```js
let strings = ['language.0.name', 'language.0', 'language'];
// parse function
const parseFormStr = (s) => s.split('.').reduce((a, c) => a + `[${c}]`);
// test loop
strings.forEach(s => console.log([s, ' => ', parseFormStr(s)].join('')));
```

Comment: Thank you man, I now we can send json like this. JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeArray())
but in is it impossible in vuejs ? and in this way can I upload image?

Comment: You have to use FormData to send image. `const data = new FormData(formElement)` and make sure to set appropriate multi-part content type header. Don't need any of this string code when you do that

Answer (score 0):

Here's my bad implementation that I did not bother to optimize:

```js
const string = "language.0.name";

function toKeyNotation(s: string) {
  const string = s;

  const m = string.match(/.\d./g);
  const n = m.map((s) => s.slice(1, 2));

  const a = string.split(/.\d./g);

  let r = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    const newString = `[${n[i]}]`;
    r += a[i];
    r += newString;
  }

  r += a[a.length - 1];

  return r;
}

console.log(toKeyNotation(string)); // returns 'language[0]name'
```

Comment: Sorry I updated my question .. is it any way to use regular expression only?

Comment: in that case the above answers wuould suffice ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Following Function will help you with es6 string to formdata

```js
function filterData(str) {
  str = str.split(".");
  let str1 = "";
  str.forEach((element) => {
    str1 === "" ? (str1 = element) : (str1 += "[" + element + "]");
  });
  console.log(str1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" onkeydown="filterData(this.value)" />
  </body>
</html>
```